# Angular 8 - How to use @HostBinding instead of host in a derivative

Tags: angular

I found this very nice directive on Medium (https://medium.com/@sub.metu/angular-fallback-for-broken-images-5cd05c470f08):

```
import {Directive, Input, HostBinding} from '@angular/core'
@Directive({
    selector: 'img[default]',
    host: {
      '(error)':'updateUrl()',
      '(load)': 'load()',
      '[src]':'src'
     }
  })

 export class ImagePreloadDirective {
    @Input() src:string;
    @Input() default:string;
    @HostBinding('class') className

    updateUrl() {
      this.src = this.default;
    }
    load(){
      this.className = 'image-loaded';
    }
  }
```

However, TSlint tells me I should use `HostBinding` instead of `host` on line 4. But I've found no documentation to help me implement this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always configure tslint as you want:

**tslint.json**

```
...
"no-host-metadata-property": false,
```

If you want to follow Angular recommendations then you can rewrite it like:

**image-preload.directive.ts**

```typescript
import { Directive, Input, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[default]',
})
export class ImagePreloadDirective {
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('src')
  src: string;

  @Input() default: string;

  @HostBinding('class') className;

  @HostListener('error')
  updateUrl() {
    this.src = this.default;
  }

  @HostListener('load')
  load() {
    this.className = 'image-loaded';
  }
}
```

Comment: I never knew that you could combine Input and Hostbinding, that's awesome.